# How to use + or * in Notepad++ regular expression positive lookbehind (?<=exp)

Tags: regex, notepad++

The task is to find the number 999 in `ps.SDR_FLOW_SUBSCRIBER_1DAY_999`

I can use `(?<=1DAY_)[0-9]{3}` to find the 999, but if I add more conditions, Notepad++ will report the error `Invalid regular expression`.

So, how can I use `+` or `*` in this condition?

[image]

Comment: This may be present in the image you included, but I can't see it (corporate networks might block `*.imgur.com`) : what is your target RE with the `*` or `+` included?

Comment: Since it's probably your problem : Notepad++ uses the boost regex engine, which doesn't allow variable-width lookbehind (most regex engine don't) -> using a quantifier in a lookbehind will always fail

Comment: You say the task is to find the number. But, if that were the case, you don't need `(?<=1DAY_)`. All you're seeing if using _Find All_ is a number. How does it relate to anything in the document ? Say you want to qualify it with `1DAY_` using `[1A-Z]+_` why wouldn't you like to see the qualifier highlighted as well ? It doesn't make sense.  If you're using it in a replacement situation, just wrap the part in a capture group, then write it back. `([1A-Z]+_)[0-9]{3}`. You could use the `\K` operator to exclude it from the match `[1A-Z]+_\K[0-9]{3}` but why use it just for the sake of using it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `\K` match reset operator that is an excellent positive lookbehind replacement for non-overlapping matches.

E.g. you may use

```
1\w+_\K[0-9]{3}
```

to match `1`, then 1+ word chars and a `_` that will all be omitted from the match, and only 3 digits will be left in the match value.

Surely, it would make sense to exclude an underscore from the shorthand character class `\w`, and use `[^\W_]+` instead (to match any 1+ alphanumeric chars), but the main point is using `\K` operator here.

[image]